# window.open causes an exception

Tags: javascript, htmlunit, window.open

Clicking on HtmlAnchor should pop up a window. The pop up window actually gets created but the program crashes with the following error message: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking open.
I have enclosed both the code and also the console printouts.
The href attribute equals:

```
Javascript:window.open('https://www.apps.amway.hu/shop/los/los.aspx?lng=hu', 'points_window', 'width=830,height=580,location=0,menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,status=1,titlebar=0,toolbar=0');void(0);
```

I would appreciate help.`

```
enter code here


link = (HtmlAnchor) page.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/a");

System.out.println("link text= ,"+link.asText()+"  hreg= "+link.getHrefAttribute());

page= (HtmlPage) link.click();
```

It produces the following error report:

```
 com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking open
    ======= EXCEPTION START ========
    Exception class=[java.lang.RuntimeException]
    com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: Exception invoking open
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:894)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:775)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:751)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:739)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:910)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.doClickStateUpdate(HtmlAnchor.java:133)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.doClickStateUpdate(HtmlAnchor.java:211)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:999)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.click(HtmlAnchor.java:83)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:944)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:884)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:865)
        at PopUpAmw.PopUpAmw.main(PopUpAmw.java:191)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking open
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:182)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:448)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1540)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:413)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:292)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:766)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:879)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined (https://www.apps.amway.hu/Shop/JS/Tealeaf/TeaLeaf.js#270)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:894)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:824)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:796)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:2454)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:259)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:325)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement$2.run(DomElement.java:1389)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.fireEvent(DomElement.java:1394)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1201)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:253)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:524)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:391)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.openWindow(WebClient.java:874)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window.open(Window.java:453)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:153)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined (https://www.apps.amway.hu/Shop/JS/Tealeaf/TeaLeaf.js#270)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3899)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3924)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3940)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3951)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1492)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1247)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:815)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:879)
    ... 48 more
Enclosed exception: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception invoking open
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:182)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:448)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1540)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:413)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:292)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3264)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:115)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$3.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:766)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:879)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:775)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:751)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:739)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:910)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.doClickStateUpdate(HtmlAnchor.java:133)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.doClickStateUpdate(HtmlAnchor.java:211)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:999)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor.click(HtmlAnchor.java:83)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:944)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:884)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.click(DomElement.java:865)
    at PopUpAmw.PopUpAmw.main(PopUpAmw.java:191)
Caused by: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined (https://www.apps.amway.hu/Shop/JS/Tealeaf/TeaLeaf.js#270)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:894)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:824)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:796)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:2454)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeEventListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:259)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventListenersContainer.executeBubblingListeners(EventListenersContainer.java:325)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.event.EventTarget.fireEvent(EventTarget.java:188)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement$2.run(DomElement.java:1389)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:628)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:515)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.DomElement.fireEvent(DomElement.java:1394)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeEventHandlersIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1201)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:253)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:524)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:391)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:309)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.openWindow(WebClient.java:874)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.Window.open(Window.java:453)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:153)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot read property "length" from undefined (https://www.apps.amway.hu/Shop/JS/Tealeaf/TeaLeaf.js#270)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3915)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:3899)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:3924)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError2(ScriptRuntime.java:3940)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.undefReadError(ScriptRuntime.java:3951)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getObjectProp(ScriptRuntime.java:1492)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1247)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:800)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:815)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:879)
    ... 48 more
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

Answer (score 0):

Please file an HtmlUnit issue. Include the version and the complete StackTrace.

Comment: The version of HtmlUnit: 2.25

Comment: Stack trace (the complete stack trace is too long so I will split it ):